# How do i use the deep sleep function from the Node MCU correctly?

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

i have an Node MCU and want because i have it running with a batterie to go to deep sleep mode until i press the reset button. So it should use ~20 uA but it uses 12.7 mA. Do i something wrong with this function?

```
      ESP.deepSleep(0);
```

Comment: and the USB chip?

Comment: @Juraj what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESP8266 will go into deep sleep mode, but there are other components on the board which also consume power, like the USB2serial converter and the LEDs.

So you should use a board which is optimized for the low power use case.

To quote [this page](https://diyi0t.com/how-to-reduce-the-esp8266-power-consumption/):
*"The deep-sleep mode reduces the current consumption of the ESP8266 by 44% for the NodeMCU and by 64% for the WeMos D1 Mini compared to the use of no power mode"*

It also depends if you power the board via the USB connector with 5V or directly the 3.3V pin.